# FreeMarker Map of String and List

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying to add sequence as a value in a map:

```
<#assign client_sequence=['a', 'b']>
{
    clients: ${client_sequence},
    usecase_key: usecase_value,
    other_key: other_value
}
```

In the above example, client_sequence will be passed from another module which cannot be changed. I have replaced it to illustrate.

I am getting following error:

```
 For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):
```

==> client_sequence  [in nameless template at line 3, column 16]

---

```
  FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
```

### - Failed at: ${client_sequence}  [in nameless template at line 3, column 14]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use FreeMarker sequence's [join](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_join) built in with comma:

```
<#assign client_sequence=['a', 'b','c']>
{
    clients: ${client_sequence?join(", ")}
    usecase_key: usecase_value,
    other_key: other_value
}
```

> Concatenates the items of a sequence to a single string, with the given separator.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm

Comment: What if client_sequence is a map?

Comment: @sukhwantprafullit you can use `?values` or `?keys`, e.g. clients: `${client_sequence?keys?join(", ")}`